# Stanford CoreNLP BasicPipelineExample doesn't work

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to get started with Stanford CoreNLP and can't even get past the very first simple example from here.

> https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Here is my code:

```
package stanford.corenlp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

    private void test2() {
        // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        // read some text in the text variable
        String text = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.";

        // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        // run all Annotators on this text
        pipeline.annotate(document);

    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      StanfordNLP nlp = new StanfordNLP();
      nlp.test2();
  }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Adding annotator tokenize
No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:791)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:312)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:265)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:73)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.posTagger(AnnotatorImplementations.java:55)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$42(StanfordCoreNLP.java:496)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getDefaultAnnotatorPool$65(StanfordCoreNLP.java:533)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:118)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:146)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:447)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:146)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:133)
    at stanford.corenlp.StanfordNLP.test2(StanfordNLP.java:93)
    at stanford.corenlp.StanfordNLP.main(StanfordNLP.java:108)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:789)
    ... 16 more
C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to add to the class path stanford-corenlp-3.8.0.jar.  That makes the red error marks in NetBeans go away.  But you also need to add stanford-corenlp-3.8.0-models.jar to the class path to prevent the error I documented.  Adding the folder it resides in to the classpath doesn't work.  Details like this should never be left out of beginner documentation!

Now if you continue with the example and add in the new stuff, more errors occur.  For example, the code will then look like:

```
package stanford.corenlp;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import com.google.common.io.Files;

    import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefChain;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
    import edu.stanford.nlp.util.PropertiesUtils;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

        private void test2() {
            // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(
            PropertiesUtils.asProperties(
                "annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,natlog",
                "ssplit.isOneSentence", "true",
                "parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz",
                "tokenize.language", "en"));

            // read some text in the text variable
            String text = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.";

            // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
            Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

            // run all Annotators on this text
            pipeline.annotate(document);

            // these are all the sentences in this document
            // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
            List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

            for (CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
                // traversing the words in the current sentence
                // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
                for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
                    // this is the text of the token
                    String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
                    // this is the POS tag of the token
                    String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
                    // this is the NER label of the token
                    String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);

                    System.out.println("word="+word +", pos="+pos +", ne="+ne);
                }

                // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
                Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

                // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
                SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
            }

            // This is the coreference link graph
            // Each chain stores a set of mentions that link to each other,
            // along with a method for getting the most representative mention
            // Both sentence and token offsets start at 1!
            Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = 
                document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
        }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          StanfordNLP nlp = new StanfordNLP();
          nlp.test2();
      }

    }
```

And the stack trace becomes:

```
run:
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.6 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator parse
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:187)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.loadModel(ParserAnnotator.java:219)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.<init>(ParserAnnotator.java:121)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.parse(AnnotatorImplementations.java:115)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$50(StanfordCoreNLP.java:504)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getDefaultAnnotatorPool$65(StanfordCoreNLP.java:533)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:118)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:146)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:447)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:150)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:146)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:133)
    at stanford.corenlp.StanfordNLP.test2(StanfordNLP.java:95)
    at stanford.corenlp.StanfordNLP.main(StanfordNLP.java:145)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:309)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:184)
    ... 14 more
C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I finally got past this point by downloading and adding to the classpath stanford-english-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar which you can get from the "English" download link here:

> https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

You need to do this despite the message on the Download page saying that everything needed for English is already provided in the corenlp download!

Answer (score 0):

[2019-12-31] For clarity / reference; note: Linux terminal.

Download `CoreNLP 3.9.2` | `stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip`, https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html] and extract it.

```sh
pwd; ls -l
  /mnt/Vancouver/apps/CoreNLP/src-local/zzz
  -rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 393239982 Dec 31 14:13 stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip

unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip
  # ...

ls -l
  drwxrwxr-x 5 victoria victoria      4096 Oct  8  2018 stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
  -rw-r--r-- 1 victoria victoria 393239982 Dec 31 14:13 stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip
```

Save the "BasicPipelineExample.java" code

- https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html#quickstart-with-convenience-wrappers
- https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/examples/BasicPipelineExample.java

in a file named `BasicPipelineExample.java` :

```sh
/mnt/Vancouver/apps/CoreNLP/src-local/zzz/BasicPipelineExample.java
```

Compile it

```sh
pwd     ## "sanity check"
  /mnt/Vancouver/apps/CoreNLP/src-local/zzz/

javac -cp stanford-corenlp-3.9.2.jar  BasicPipelineExample.java -Xdiags:verbose
```

which gives the Java class file `BasicPipelineExample.class`, and run it from that dir,

```sh
java -cp .:* BasicPipelineExample
```

---

**Addendum**

The code above describes access to CoreNLP in the Java environment, as described here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html#quickstart-with-convenience-wrappers

For those more inclined (myself included) Stanford provides basically the same functionality in a Python environment, as described here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/corenlp_client.html

E.g.,

```py
import stanfordnlp
from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient
# JSON output [default]:
client = CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', \
    'parse', 'depparse','coref'], timeout=30000, memory='16G')
# Plain-text ourput (much more compact):
client = CoreNLPClient(annotators='tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, \
    depparse, coref', output_format='text',  timeout=30000, memory='16G')
text = 'Breast cancer susceptibility gene 1 (BRCA1) is a tumor suppressor protein.'
# This auto-starts the client() instance:
ann = client.annotate(text)
  # ....
sentence = ann.sentence[0]
print(sentence)
  # ... copious output ...
print(ann)
  # ... more succinct ...
```

Note: if you are using the `output_format='text'` argument you can do this

```py
print(ann)
```

but not this

```py
sentence = ann.sentence[0]
print(sentence)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sentence'
```

Using the `stanfordnlp` package you can also set up a pipeline, as described here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/

E.g.,

```py
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download('en')
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline()
text = 'Bananas are an excellent source of potassium.'
text_nlp = nlp(text)
text_nlp.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

Lastly -- though I find the functionality limited (cf. the Stanford-authored CoreNLP libraries) -- somewhat similar results are available by accessing CoreNLP in spaCy: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanfordnlp

```py
import stanfordnlp
from spacy_stanfordnlp import StanfordNLPLanguage
snlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline(lang="en")
nlp = StanfordNLPLanguage(snlp)
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii. He was elected president in 2008.")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.dep_)
  # ...
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56635121/1904943, which provides some interesting comments, e.g. differences between StanfordNLP / CoreNLP, as well as subtleties to note when doing dependency parses over negations (CoreNLP vs. NLTK) ...

Comment: I created a Gist with the code shown, with the output (including the error described above, and its solution): https://gist.github.com/victoriastuart/9d63ad8fd7e05c65ddcbd02199ee81f3