# Dependency parsing in python stanford core NLP

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I am working on NLP project based on stanford Coe NLP.I have got the sentiment corresponding to each text/sentence-thanks to the document [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879532/stanford-nlp-for-python)
Now I need to get the list of nouns and related adjectives for each text in data frame column,there by I can bucket them based on adjective sentiment.I tried the stanford website,but didnt find any sample function /code to achieve this.can I get a help on this please. TIA

For my text_df dataframe,

```
with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['sentiment','tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', 'depparse'], timeout=60000, memory='16G') as client:
    # submit the request to the server
    for ind in text_df.index:                                                                                    
        ann = client.annotate(text_df["text1"][ind])
        dp = sentence.basicDependencies
        token_dict = {sentence.token[i].tokenEndIndex- 
        offset:sentence.token[i].word for i in range(0, 
        len(sentence.token))}offset += len(sentence.token)

        out_parse = [(dp.edge[i].source, dp.edge[i].target,dp.edge[i].dep,) 
        for i in range(0, len(dp.edge))]
            for source, target,dep in out_parse:
                print(dep, token_dict[source], token_dict[target])
                text_df1['dep'][j]=dep
                text_df1['source'][j]=token_dict[source]
                text_df1['target'][j]=token_dict[target]
                text_df1['Sent_id'][j]=text_sentences
                j=j+1
            for token in sentence.token:
                text_df2['target'][h]=token.word
                text_df2['pos'][h]=token.pos
                text_df2['Sent_id'][h]=text_sentences
                h=h+1
```

This code basically creates dataframe with dependency parser(dep),source and target tokens in one dataframe(text_df1) and each token with POS value(text_df2) in another. My requirement in to get each token/word in a sentence with their nouns and related adjectives.Finally I combined those two tables and got the required dataframe.
But my issue  now is ,I have sentence "raj went to office and his office is very far"I am seeing the given below for the text_df1:
nsubj went raj
nmod went office
dep went is
case office to
cc office and
conj office office
nmod:poss office his
advmod is far
advmod far very

Ideally I should see a dependency parser with nsubj(far,office) but i am missing this particular value,could somewhen help me out where I missed ..?

when I checked in http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp, the same sentences I am seeing nsubj(far,office) as well..

I guess I need to write the python code to generate 'Universal dependencies, enhanced 'in their website.
Can anyone help pls

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Does your question answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527814/stanford-typed-dependencies-using-corenlp-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stanford typed dependencies using coreNLP in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527814/stanford-typed-dependencies-using-corenlp-in-python)

Comment: @VenkataShivaram Thanks a lot for the link! It helped a lot,but came across another issue-I gave the sentence -"Miller is nice but Phill is good and he sold her fast car" I am getting the dependencies as -(Nice,Miller),(good,Phill),(car,fast)-I was expacting as (fast,car) bu it parsed as 'amod',so kinda confused.Could you please help here.. TIA

Comment: @alexisdevarennes >>Yes!! It helps a lot,but I need to understand how the parsing works and identifying nsubj and amod here..Actually my requirement  is to get the noun and related adjective for each sentence is a dataframe.. TIA

Comment: @KrishnalekhaMoolayil Well! Can you please share the code that you had tried.

Comment: For my text_df dataframe,                                                                                    with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['sentiment','tokenize','ssplit','pos','lemma','ner', 'depparse'], timeout=60000, memory='16G') as client:
    # submit the request to the server
    for ind in text_df.index:

Comment: @VenkataShivaram I have updated my query ..can you check pls